# Displaying images when click on next button

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application with next and previous buttons. Between those buttons, I want to place numbers.  This would look like:

```
PreviousBtn 1 2 3 4 5 NextBtn
```

How can I place the five numbers between the buttons?
Instead of ButtonField I have a custom button class to implement buttons. I am using the following code.

```
numberBtn = new ImgButtonField[ total().size()];
for (i = 0; i <total().size(); i++) {
    numberBtn[i] = new ImgButtonField(total().elementAt(i).getNo());
}
```

the numberBtn is having total 40 numbers. How can I display (PreviousBtn 1  2  3  4  5 NextBtn) format, if I clicked on next or pre buttons it should show (PreviousBtn 2  3  4  5  6 NextBtn).

I have images corresponding to the numbers suppose if I click on 1 it should display one image on the screen and so on. So how to place these all images without giving all image resource paths for each corresponding number. Is any simpler way to get all images at a strech when numbers are clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Place that 40 image button in to horizontal field manager.. Scroll the manager whenever you press next and previous button.. This is simple way to do this..

Comment: Hi David thanks for reply.But how to display 5 numbers between next and previous buttons.Now I able to place only one number between them.

Comment: you want customize HM and its size should be total length of 5 button

Comment: yes I want to customize the HorizontalManager and  I should display like this (PreviousBtn 1 2 3 4 5 NextBtn).When click on next button it should show (2 3 4 5 6) .